# Picasso showing image in a Landscape mode

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

Using Picasso library to download images from server and to place in a ImageView, but every time it's showing images in a Landscape mode only, even image originally in Portrait mode.

I have some images in Landscape mode and some in Portrait mode but while downloading and showing into ImageView getting in Landscape mode only !

Usage of **Picasso**:

```
        Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
        .load(imageURL) // web image url
        .fit().centerInside()
        .transform(transformation)
        .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .into(viewHolder.imageView , new Callback() {
            ....
            }
        });
```

Comment: you can rotate our images with picasso just need to add `.rotate(degrees)` in picasso load() method

Comment: if you are downloading from server you need to add extra field 'orientation' along with its name and path so while downloading you can check the orientation and can set it accordingly

Comment: @KaranMer please post .rotate(90) as your answer, so i can accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To rotate image using Picasso, all you need to do is set degrees to rotate in picasso's load() method, as below

```
Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
        .load(imageURL) // web image url
        .fit().centerInside()
        .transform(transformation)
        .rotate(90)                    //if you want to rotate by 90 degrees
        .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .into(viewHolder.imageView , new Callback() {
            ....
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

You can simply provide the required angle for the image view as follows,

```
 <ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:rotation="90" />
```

Comment: this will rotate the whole imageview

Answer (score 0):

This is correct :   Picasso.get().load(image.url).rotate(90F).into(view)